# How to add another data to items loaded by Paging Library?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-paging

I use Android Architecture Components to build my app. There is Paging Library to load items with Room generated `DataSource`. Also there is `BoundaryCallback` to get new data from server and store it in the database. It works fine, all is reactive, changes in the database come into PagedList.

But now I need to these items get some additional data, some calculations before they come into `PagesList` and `RecyclerView`. These calculations is not so fast to executing them on main thread in RecyclerView ViewHolder (actually I need to get additional data from the database or even from the server). So I supposed that I need to write my custom DataSource and make calculations there and then pass these *processed* items to `PagedList`.

I created my `ItemKeyedDataSource` (I'm not sure this is correct, because I load data from database, but this data source type is designed for network, but I don't think this is critical), and make queries in Dao that return `List` of items. After I got a "page", I make calculations to items and then pass it to callback. It works, `PagedList` gets *processed* items.

But unfortunately there is **no reactivity** with this approach. No changes in database come to my PagedList. I tried to return `LiveData<List>` from Dao and add `observeForever()` listener in `DataSource` but it fails since you can't run it on background thread.

I watched Room generated `DataSource.Factory` and `LimitOffsetDataSource` but it doesn't look good to me since you need to pass table names to observe changes and other unclear things.

I suppose that I need to use invalidate(), but I don't because I have no idea where it should be.

There is 3 main questions:

1. Is it right to process items in `DataSource` before they come to `RecyclerView` or there is a better place?
2. Should I use `PositionalDataSource` instead of `ItemKeyedDataSource`?
3. How can I add Room reactivity to custom `DataSource`?

Comment: yes, you have to use `invalidate()`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/DataSource#updating-paged-data

Comment: @pskink how can I unserstand when to call invalidate() and where to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I've found a mistake in my `DataSource.Factory`. Instead of creating DataSource object in `create()` method I just returned object which was passed to that factory (I saw it in one popular article on Medium). And because of that I couldn't invalidate my `DataSource`. But now I create `DataSource` in that method and invalidation works.

The only problem is to understand **where and when** to invalidate. For now I've found some workaround: make a query in Dao that returns `LiveData` of last item, and then observe it in my Activity to understand that data was modified and call `invalidate()`. But I'm not sure this is a good solution. Maybe you know a better one.

Comment: "how can I unserstand when to call invalidate() and where to do it?" -- you are the one updating the database. If you have repository operations that affect the table(s) used by your query, you know when to invalidate.

Comment: @CommonsWare but there can be different repositories (I have a lot of tables connected to my item). I don't have DataSource instance in all of them. Is it bad to observe LiveData as a signal to invalidation?

Comment: "Is it bad to observe LiveData as a signal to invalidation?" -- I don't understand how it works, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You may add invalidationTracker in your DataSource:

```
dbRoom.getInvalidationTracker().addObserver(
            object : InvalidationTracker.Observer("your_table") {
                override fun onInvalidated(@NonNull tables: Set<String>) {
                    invalidate()
                }
            })
```

Comment: is it working also when using other wrappers than Room? like Greendao